# long double cast to int data type effects double division precision (powerpc, ppc32)

Tags: c++, gcc, precision, powerpc

Consider following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    double a=54;
    double b=10;
    long double g=3;
    std::cout << a/b << std::endl;
    int i=g;
    std::cout << a/b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled on x86 platform gives result as expected:

```
$ ./a.out
5.4
5.4
```

Compiled on PowerPc (ppc32) platform result is a bit different:

```
# ./a.out.ppc
5.4
5.39999
```

It seems that if 'long double' is casted to 'int' data type it effects on 'double' division precision.

I don't know why it is happening and how to fix it. Any help please?

```
Platform: Linux
Compiler:
$ /usr/bin/powerpc-e500v2-linux-gnu-g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/powerpc-e500v2-linux-gnu-g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/powerpc-e500v2-linux-gnu/9.4.0/lto-wrapper
Target: powerpc-e500v2-linux-gnu
Configured with: /var/tmp/portage/cross-powerpc-e500v2-linux-gnu/gcc-9.4.0/work/gcc-9.4.0/configure --host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --target=powerpc-e500v2-linux-gnu --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/powerpc-e500v2-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/9.4.0 --includedir=/usr/lib/gcc/powerpc-e500v2-linux-gnu/9.4.0/include --datadir=/usr/share/gcc-data/powerpc-e500v2-linux-gnu/9.4.0 --mandir=/usr/share/gcc-data/powerpc-e500v2-linux-gnu/9.4.0/man --infodir=/usr/share/gcc-data/powerpc-e500v2-linux-gnu/9.4.0/info --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/lib/gcc/powerpc-e500v2-linux-gnu/9.4.0/include/g++-v9 --with-python-dir=/share/gcc-data/powerpc-e500v2-linux-gnu/9.4.0/python --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --enable-obsolete --enable-secureplt --disable-werror --with-system-zlib --enable-nls --without-included-gettext --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-checking=release --with-bugurl=https://bugs.gentoo.org/ --with-pkgversion='Gentoo 9.4.0 p1' --disable-esp --enable-libstdcxx-time --enable-poison-system-directories --with-sysroot=/usr/powerpc-e500v2-linux-gnu --disable-bootstrap --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-clocale=gnu --disable-multilib --disable-fixed-point --enable-e500-double --enable-targets=all --enable-libgomp --disable-libssp --disable-libada --disable-systemtap --disable-vtable-verify --disable-libvtv --enable-lto --without-isl --enable-default-pie --enable-default-ssp
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.4.0 (Gentoo 9.4.0 p1)
```

Pure C version & assembly:

```
$ cat main2.cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double a=54;
    double b=10;
    long double g=3;
    printf("%f\n", a/b);
    int i=g;
    printf("%f\n", a/b);
    return 0;
}

$ /usr/bin/powerpc-e500v2-linux-gnu-gcc -S main2.cpp -o a.out.asm

$ cat a.out.asm
        .file   "main2.cpp"
        .machine ppc
        .section        ".text"
        .section        .rodata
        .align 2
.LC6:
        .string "%f\n"
        .section        ".got2","aw"
        .align 2
.LCTOC1 = .+32768
.LC1:
        .long .LC0
.LC3:
        .long .LC2
.LC5:
        .long .LC4
.LC7:
        .long .LC6
        .section        ".text"
        .align 2
        .globl main
        .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        stwu 1,-96(1)
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 96
        mflr 0
        stw 0,100(1)
        stw 30,88(1)
        stw 31,92(1)
        .cfi_offset 65, 4
        .cfi_offset 30, -8
        .cfi_offset 31, -4
        mr 31,1
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 31
        bcl 20,31,.L3
.L3:
        mflr 30
        addis 30,30,.LCTOC1-.L3@ha
        addi 30,30,.LCTOC1-.L3@l
        lwz 9,.LC1-.LCTOC1(30)
        lfd 0,0(9)
        stfd 0,48(31)
        lwz 9,.LC3-.LCTOC1(30)
        lfd 0,0(9)
        stfd 0,56(31)
        lwz 9,.LC5-.LCTOC1(30)
        lfd 0,0(9)
        lfd 1,8(9)
        addi 9,31,64
        stfd 0,0(9)
        stfd 1,8(9)
        lfd 12,48(31)
        lfd 0,56(31)
        fdiv 0,12,0
        fmr 1,0
        lwz 3,.LC7-.LCTOC1(30)
        creqv 6,6,6
        bl printf+32768@plt
        addi 9,31,64
        lfd 0,0(9)
        lfd 1,8(9)
        mffs 12
        mtfsb1 31
        mtfsb0 30
        fadd 0,0,1
        mtfsf 1,12
        fctiwz 0,0
        stfd 0,24(31)
        lwz 9,28(31)
        stw 9,44(31)
        lfd 12,48(31)
        lfd 0,56(31)
        fdiv 0,12,0
        fmr 1,0
        lwz 3,.LC7-.LCTOC1(30)
        creqv 6,6,6
        bl printf+32768@plt
        li 9,0
        mr 3,9
        addi 11,31,96
        lwz 0,4(11)
        mtlr 0
        lwz 30,-8(11)
        lwz 31,-4(11)
        .cfi_def_cfa 11, 0
        mr 1,11
        .cfi_restore 31
        .cfi_restore 30
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 1
        blr
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
        .size   main,.-main
        .section        .rodata
        .align 3
.LC0:
        .long   1078657024
        .long   0
        .align 3
.LC2:
        .long   1076101120
        .long   0
        .align 4
.LC4:
        .long   1074266112
        .long   0
        .long   0
        .long   0
        .ident  "GCC: (Gentoo 9.4.0 p1) 9.4.0"
        .gnu_attribute 4, 5
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: Is your second `std::cout << a/b << std::endl;` intentional?

Comment: Which compiler(s)/version(s)?   And what compilation/build options?   Those sort of things are relevant since you're asking about the reason for different output on different platforms

Comment: What system are you using? What implementation of stnadard library are you using? Can you reproduce it in C with `printf`? With `strtod`?

Comment: Changining g++ to gcc and cout to printf: printf("%f\n", a/b); does not change anything.

Comment: The question is not why result is different on different platforms but why result of division changes afrer long double to int casting?

Comment: Still, what compiler flags are you using? Could you do like alias with a buffer like [here](https://godbolt.org/z/osWrG87ff)? Please show the output from `%a` `printf` format specifier. Please show the generated assembly code, from C with `printf`s will be simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found the bug I think:

GCC assembly of 'long double' to 'int' casting:

```
  7c:   39 3f 00 40     addi    r9,r31,64
  80:   c8 09 00 00     lfd     f0,0(r9)
  84:   c8 29 00 08     lfd     f1,8(r9)
  88:   fd 80 04 8e     mffs    f12
  8c:   ff e0 00 4c     mtfsb1  31
  90:   ff c0 00 8c     mtfsb0  30
  94:   fc 00 08 2a     fadd    f0,f0,f1
  98:   fc 02 65 8e     mtfsf   1,f12
  9c:   fc 00 00 1e     fctiwz  f0,f0
  a0:   d8 1f 00 18     stfd    f0,24(r31)
  a4:   81 3f 00 1c     lwz     r9,28(r31)
  a8:   91 3f 00 2c     stw     r9,44(r31)
```

This is crucial:

```
mtfsb1  31
mtfsb0  30
```

It is manipulating on Rounding bits. These bits are not restored after 'cast' operation. IMO it is GCC bug but I cannot find any reference.